# How to get just one user data in Laravel with eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-8

I use Laravel 8. I want to get the user proccess course, but I get all users proccess.

**In User.php**

```
  public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
    }
```

**Course.php**

```
public function progresses()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Progress::class);
 }
```

Progress.php is empty.

**Course table**

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Progress table**

```
    Schema::create('progress', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('percent');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**CourseController**

```
public function index()
{
    $userCourses = User::where('id', 1)->with('courses.progresses')->first();
    return $userCourses;
}
```

And this return:

[image]

But I only wanted proccess where user_id = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`With()` method can constrain eager loads with a specific array annotation. This is also described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```
$userId = 1;

$userCourses = User::where('id', $userId)
    ->with(
        [
            'courses.progresses' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userId)
            },
        ]
     )->first();
```

Comment: Yep, just go with that answer ;-) Might want to use `find($userId)` instead of `where('id', $userId)` though and also get rid of the `first()` that way - you have to do the find last, however.